# Thai alphabet romanizations?

Tags: alphabets, thai, romanization

Is there any standard system of romanization for the Thai alphabet (including consonants, vowels, tones, numbers, and their combinations), or is any such romanization system quite arbitrary? Can someone please apply the complete list? Also, are the names of (eg. chicken for the first consonant) etc... given next to the sound of each letter combination pretty standard as part of the way the Thai alphabet is taught? Thank you for your explanation, and sorry if I'm just a day zero beginner.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://www.loc.gov/catdir/cpso/romanization/thai.pdf?

Comment: Yes, but in view of the fact that tones are not romanized, is there a fix for that? Also, why are characters appearing in the final position romanized differently? Are they pronounced differently there? Thanks.

Comment: @JackMaddington: Yes just like in other languages such as Korean, consonant letters in Thai can represent different sounds at syllable end than at syllable start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official system of Romanization of the Thai languiage is [Royal Thai General System of Transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Thai_General_System_of_Transcription) (RTGS). All road signs, landmarks, and so on are to be transcribed according to RTGS.

RTGS has certain **pro's**, likewise it uses a plain Latin alphabet, no tone marks, no vowel length marks, etc. And these are also **con's** (e.g. you can't read it properly when you need).

There are plenty of unofficial systems. For example, one of the prominent resources for Thai language learners, [Thai-Language.com](http://www.thai-language.com/default.aspx?nav=control), has several systems of Romanization:

[image: Romanization systems of Thai]

**Note** as you see, I prefer IPA over RTGS as it provides with complete information over the tones, vowel lengths, and so on.

**Yet another note:** Paiboon is a publishing agency that has published a famous book for Thai language learners, so it takes its own place within the system.

**A personal note**: ISO 11940 is a horrible thing, Google Translate uses it, so stay way from it. :-)

---

As for the list of consonants and the meanings of the words, [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_alphabet#Alphabetic) seems to be a good source:

[image: Thai consonants]

Comment: What it's wrong with ISO 11940. Is it the list of supported fonts, or is there something inherently wrong in the encoding? So, what do you suggest I use instead for formatting documents and when texting on my Android phone? Thanks.

Comment: So what is the difference between the *kho* in *kho khai* and the *kho* in *kho khuat*? Judging just from the table, their pronunciations look exactly the same. Thanks.

Comment: Would you recommend the *Thai for beginners* book by *Paiboon* as a purchase? Is it worth buying in today's highly digital age? I am a beginner learner but experienced in other languages. Thanks.

Comment: I could find the book on the Amazon store but not on my Android Kindle app.

Comment: @JackMaddington, okay, (1) ISO 11940 (in my opinion) does not give information to correctly produce the sounds. This must be an ultimate goal for any transcription. This is **not** an encoding, this is only a transcription system. One's smartphone is usually equipped with *keyboard layouts*, not with transcription systems. If you need to SMS your friend telling them "I'm going to Sattahip", just use the common spelling (which is RTGS).

Comment: (2) the difference between the consonants: all three **kho** represent an equivalent sound, aspirated "k". They belong to different [**consonant classes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_alphabet#Consonants) hence they govern the different tonal rules. (3) I never insisted that Benjawan Baker's book is a must; it's just a mainstream in Thai lang learning methodology. To me, a paper book is still good nowadays because you can draw margin note highlights. [YMMV](http://uk.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ymmv), however.

Comment: Thanks. For all it matters, and for what I know, ISO encodings are not meant to provide pronunciation information, but are merely designed to support the storing of the characters in a computer. That said I've got to admit I've never seen a Thai PC keyboard so I know nothing about native keyboard layouts. To input them, you need an input method. This allows for either Roman or Thai characters to appear on the keyboard and software does the conversion. Thanks.

Comment: Note that every transcription is an inherently lossy transformation; once you've got "kh", you no longer know which of three kh's it was. So there's no possibility to type a transcription and get a normal Thai text. For toponyms, however, RTGS is just fine.

Comment: That's a good point your making, thank you. So there will be no input method based on roman characters unlike with systems such as Chinese pinyin input. From the Wikipedia article I gather that *kho khuat* is no longer used in written Thai, although its pronunciation is exactly the same as that of *kho khai*. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40546/discussion-between-bytebuster-and-jack-maddington).

Comment: @bytebuster: I'm no fan of ISO 11940 but to be fair, it is not and was not designed to be a *transcription*. It is one of the very few instances of a true *transliteration*. It was designed to be a one-to-one representation of Thai writing, not of Thai sounds. That may have some pros but some uses, but it definitely has cons and it has business being in Google Translate.